# How do I improve Bluetooth communication?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, softwareserial

How do I improve Bluetooth communication?

You will see, in this image using the Bluetooth monitor application, in order to receive the "ON" response, I had to repeatedly send the "O" character:

[image]

The code that I'm using now is this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
const int RX_PIN = 0;
const int TX_PIN = 1;
char c = 'F';
boolean activar = false;

SoftwareSerial blueTooth(RX_PIN, TX_PIN);
void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  blueTooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop ()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    c = Serial.read();
    if(c == 'O'){
      activar = true;
      Serial.println("ON");
    }
    if(c == 'F'){
      activar = false;
      Serial.println("OFF");
    }
  }
  if(activar){
     detectarObstaculos();
  }
}

void detectarObstaculos(){

}
```

How could I improve the response time?

Comment: Why are you using software serial on pins 0 and 1? How do you expect to work alongside hardware serial which also uses pins 0 and 1?

Comment: I see it on a tutorial (http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-bluetooth-to-your-Arduino-project-ArduinoHC-06/)

Is that the problem then?

Comment: The (unused) bluetooth SoftwareSerial object is conflicting with the HardwareSerial object on the same pins that you *are* using. One or the other. Make your mind up.

Comment: Instructables is full of crap. It should be deleted from the internet.

Comment: Ugh, so the tutorial was bad .... I see. @Majenko, I will change my pins then

Comment: No need to change your pins. Just delete the SoftwareSerial since you're not actually using it.

Comment: @TwoDent That tutorial doesn't even mention software serial. And it isn't in the code either.